# Converting int to Enum in Java reflection

Tags: java, parsing, generics, reflection, enums

This might look similar to a few other questions but so far I have not found a solution..

I am using reflection to parse my JSONs into different classes and it saves me a lot of effort from writing class-specific parsing code, all the ints, longs, strings, and Calendars etc are easy to deal with, but now I find myself in an hell of Enum specific castings

something like:

```
else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(TransactionType.class)){
    field.set(representation, TransactionType.fromInt(Integer.parseInt(value, 10)));
}
```

the problem is that enums are stored as integers in the JSON, and I can not find a generic way to parse or cast those integers back to enums when I don't know what enum it specifically is, and I have quite a few enums so 70% of my parsing code are now dedicated to checking enum types...

is there a way that, given only field.getType().isEnum() == true, parse the int value to the enum type of that field

the enum type is declared as:

```
public static enum TransactionType{
    cashback(0),deposit(1),withdraw(2),invitation(3);
    public int code;
    TransactionType(int code){
        this.code = code;
    }
    private final static TransactionType[] map = TransactionType.values();
    public static TransactionType fromInt(int n){
        return map[n];
    }
}
```

the JSON can be a bit complicated, but enum related fields has formats as:

```
{transactionType: 1, someOtherEnumType: 0}
```

Comment: Im a bit confused as to what the int value is in relation to the enum. Could you give a short example of how you would know what the int value is of a sample enum? EG: are you using `ordinal()`?

Comment: hummm, taking the TransactionType in the question as an example: public static enum TransactionType{
        cashback(0),deposit(1),withdraw(2),invitation(3);public int code;
        TransactionType(int code){
            this.code = code;
        }}

Comment: and there is a fromtInt function : private final static TransactionType[] map = TransactionType.values();
        public static TransactionType fromInt(int n){
            return map[n];
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres how I would approch this given the information provided. Use a helper method that would sit outside your enum types that can convert any enum type that implements some interface.

---

```
public static interface Codeable {
    public int getCode();
}
public static enum TransactionType implements Codeable {
    cashback(0),deposit(1),withdraw(2),invitation(3);

    public int code; 
    TransactionType(int code) { 
        this.code = code; 
    }

    @Override
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
public static <T extends Codeable> T fromCodeToEnum(int code, Class<T> clazz) {
    for(T t : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
        if(t.getCode() == code) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
public static void main(String [] args) {
    TransactionType type = fromCodeToEnum(1, TransactionType.class);
    System.out.println(type); // deposit
}
```

---

**Edit:** Or of course you can just get the enum values and iterate through them. This could be placed wherever you want.

```
public static TransactionType findTransactionTypeByCode(int code) {

    for(TransactionType t : TransactionType.values()) {
        if(t.getCode() == code) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: tried a few different solutions, yours works like charm, following your approach I was able to solve a few other problems as well :D thank you

Answer (score 2):

Java do not support the implicit cast from literal to value.

Then enum in Java has method `ordinal()`, that returns `int` value.

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the >initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero).

An unsafe solution

```
if(field.getType().isEnum()) {
  Object itemInstance = field.getType().getEnumConstants()[ordinal];
}
```

How ever it is not recommended to us it at it was designed as part of API.

The recommendation for this case is to define in the definition of enum.

```
enum MyEnum {
 ITEM(1);

 private final int index;

 MyEnum(int index) {
   this.index;
 }
}
```

And then you should implement additional logic to serialize and deserialize, based for example on interface with default method.

```
interface SerializableEnum<E extends Enum<E>> {

        Class<E> getType();


        default E valueOf(int ordinal) {
            return getType().getEnumConstants()[ordinal];
        }
    }
```

Note that the best solution is to serialize the enum not via number but via its name.

Comment: umm yes that is pretty much how I declared my enums, the problem is that the field is enum, it could be TransactionType or MyEnum or whatever Enum, now I have that field, how do I convert an int to the actual enum type as the field is?

Comment: In case you have a field instance, you can invoke `getType()`. This will be on of TransactionType, MyEnum or others. Then you use that class, to get the array with constants.

Comment: just added some code in the question..yes I just found that I could actually simply use getEnumConstants..thanks!

Comment: @MatthewYang, Strange that you have accepted the answer that has only replied the same thing i wrote.

Comment: sorry...that was a miss click, I have unaccepted that

Comment: That's no a problem. I wonder why you did not noticed that in my answer. ;-). NVM have a nice day.

Comment: it turned out in my specific case ug's solution was the best, but up voted yours for quality :D

Answer (score 1):

[Class.getEnumConstants()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) is what you need.

```
Class<?> cls = field.getType();
if (cls.isEnum()) {
  field.set(representation, 
    cls.getEnumConstants()[Integer.parseInt(value, 10)]);
}
```

Comment: cant believe I didn't find this ealier..thanks so much

Comment: @MatthewYang this method does rely on the order in which your enum values are defined and not the "code" variable.